Color inversion issue when navigating to non-existent pages in Next.js with Tailwind
Instead of just displaying a 404 error, the entire page's colors are inverted, making the screen look very strange. This happens every time I navigate to a non-existent page.
Image of Normal Layout with White Background

Image of Unexpected Layout with Black Background (on 404 error)

I'm developing a website using Next.js and Tailwind CSS. I haven't created a custom 404 page yet, but when I navigate to a non-existent page, the entire screen's colors get inverted.
I'm unsure why this is happening and would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue.
Additional Information:

Next.js version: 14.2.8

Tailwind CSS version: 3.4.1

The issue occurs when navigating to a non-existent page.


Could this be related to any default settings or behavior of the 404 page in Next.js?

I'm guessing you have a selector selecting a parent container beneath body that overwrites the default theme, likely some theme related wrapper. Many theming libraries will wrap the app like <Theme><ActualApp/></Theme>, which wouldn't apply to the 404 page.

You can check the dev tool to see what are the classes that overwrites the default theme in the normal page, and see if they exist in the default 404 page.

I see the issue,
It can be fixed by adding your custom not-found.tsx file and return your custom jsx.
more about not found file:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found

Thank you! It’s been resolved thanks to your help. But I'm still curious about why such style properties are applied... Hmm.
